# C PCAP library unknown types error

Tags: pcap

I installed the pcap library on my linux system but when including it I get the errors

```
 /usr/include/pcap/bpf.h:88:1: error: unknown type name ‘u_int’
 /usr/include/pcap/bpf.h:108:2: error: unknown type name ‘u_int’
 /usr/include/pcap/bpf.h:1260:2: error: unknown type name ‘u_short’
 /usr/include/pcap/bpf.h:1261:2: error: unknown type name ‘u_char’
 /usr/include/pcap/bpf.h:1262:2: error: unknown type name ‘u_char’
 In file included from ../src/test.c:1:0:
 /usr/include/pcap/pcap.h:125:2: error: unknown type name ‘u_short’
 /usr/include/pcap/pcap.h:126:2: error: unknown type name ‘u_short’
 /usr/include/pcap/pcap.h:171:2: error: unknown type name ‘u_int’
 ...
 make: *** [src/test.o] Error 1
```

I included

```
 #include <pcap/pcap.h>
 #include <sys/types.h>
 #include <pcap-bpf.h>
```

in the program, what am I missing?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Make sure you do *NOT* define any of:

- `__STRICT_ANSI__`
- `_ISOC99_SOURCE`
- `_POSIX_SOURCE`
- `_POSIX_C_SOURCE`
- `_XOPEN_SOURCE`
- `_SVID_SOURCE`

when building your program; they may prevent the BSD data types, such as the ones the compile is complaining about, from being defined.

Comment: No I didn't I simply compile it with 'gcc -std=c99 test.c -o test'

Comment: Actually, yes, you *did* define at least one of them, by specifying `-std=c99`.  The GCC man page says `-std=` has the same effect as `-ansi`, and `-ansi` defines `__STRICT_ANSI__`.  `-std=c99` may define `_ISOC99_SOURCE` as well as, or instead of, `__STRICT_ANSI__`.  `-std=c99` means you want your code to be compiled as strict ISO C99, meaning it can't use any features not in ISO C99 - and libpcap isn't in ISO C99, so....  If you're trying to use C99 features and they're not supported by default, try `-std=gnu99`.

Answer (score 12):

Try adding

```
     -D_BSD_SOURCE
```

az a CFLAG to your Makefile.

Comment: Alternatively, consider `-D_GNU_SOURCE`.  This will allow you to use features derived from BSD without linking the BSD compatibility library.  See the [GNU documentation on feature test macros](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Feature-Test-Macros.html) for more information on the different values that can be specified and when you need to use the BSD compatibility library.