# error: unknown type name 'u_char' in OSX 10.11.2

Tags: c, makefile, gnu-make

I'm new to osx and I have some problems.I tried to makefile but come up with:
     `error: unknown type name 'u_char'; did you mean 'char'?`

I referred to [[C PCAP library unknown types error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15393905/c-pcap-library-unknown-types-error)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15393905/c-pcap-library-unknown-types-error) ,add `-D_BSD_SOURCE` CFLAGS to my makefile, but it doesn't help.What am I missing?

**EDIT:**

This is the code which produces the error:

```
char *computePwd(const u_char *md5) {
    static char buf[16];
    unsigned char tmp[40];
    int tmpl=0;
    tmpl = strlen(userName);
    strcpy((char*)tmp, userName);
    memcpy(tmp + tmpl, md5, 16);
    tmpl += 16;
    memcpy(buf, ComputeHash(tmp, tmpl), 16);
    memset(tmp, 0, 16);
    strcpy((char*)tmp, password);
    int i;
    for (i=0; i<16; ++i)
        buf[i] ^= tmp[i];
    return buf;
}
```

Comment: Can you post the code which produces the error?

Comment: `char *computePwd(const u_char *md5)
{
    static char buf[16];

    unsigned char tmp[40];
    int tmpl=0;
    tmpl = strlen(userName);
    strcpy((char*)tmp, userName);
    memcpy(tmp + tmpl, md5, 16);
    tmpl += 16;

    memcpy(buf, ComputeHash(tmp, tmpl), 16);

    memset(tmp, 0, 16);
    strcpy((char*)tmp, password);

    int i;
    for (i=0; i<16; ++i)
        buf[i] ^= tmp[i];
    return buf;
}`         @zvone

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add `-Du_char="unsigned char"` to `CFLAGS` or just fix the source. Using `u_char` as lazy shorthand for `unsigned char` was a common practice in legacy BSD codebases where the system headers historically exposed such a typedef. It should not be used in modern code.

Comment: It would be better to fix that error at the source, if possible. OP does not state where it appears, so this option should be taken first.

Comment: @Olaf: Which is better depends on what OP is doing. For reusing existing code in new software or actively porting existing software, fixing it is preferable, of course. But for just deploying existing legacy software/libraries with minimal fuss and maintenance effort on a modern platform, adding `-D`'s to `CFLAGS` may be the most reasonable approach.

Comment: That was my idea. Just to add that `-D` defines a macro which is a text-replacement, not a `typedef` or similar. Macros can have unexpected side-effects, because they have do not care about the normal C grammar.

Comment: @R.. I changed all the u_char to unsigned char and it works!Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Add `-D_DARWIN_C_SOURCE` and it should work.

Comment: It does. Tested with Gutenprint.

Answer (score 2):

Or you could add

```
#ifdef __APPLE__
#include <sys/types.h>
#endif
```

That fixed the same problem for me.

It includes a definition for `u_char`.

```
typedef unsigned char   u_char;
```

Comment: No huge surprise, but worth to mention: including sys/types.h solved the same problem on FreeBSD.